# applying regular expression keeping commas in R

Tags: r, regex, nlp, data-cleaning

I want to apply text cleaning with regular expressions on a dataset. However I want to keep commas because I will need to divide the text after cleaning it based on the commas (,).
the problem is that I am not extremely familiar with regex (I generally use quanteda and treat words separately as uni-grams, but in this case I can't because I need to treat the each X-gram as it is based on the commas.)

the dataset looks like this:

```
   ID         Key
   1         "Hello, dog_ food, This is it2, water"
   2         "wow! nice, love, yes"
   3         "1997"
   4           
   5         "blabla, 34 l lol, @IceCream, #nice #wow d, seriously Not"
              ....
   .
   .
```

Among the things I want to do I want to get rid of words shorter than 2 letters, get rid of anything that is not alphanumeric stem words that are uni-grams.

I tried with these commands to obtain only low-key alphanumerics and get rid of words shorter than 2 letters but I end up cancelling the commas too, and I am not sure how to do to avoid it

```
data$keys <- to_lower(data$keys)
data$keys <- str_replace_all(data$keys, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
 data$keys <- gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", data$keys) # Remove 1-2 letter words
 data$keys <- gsub("^ +| +$|( ) +", "\\1", data$keys)
```

the expected output should be something like

```
  ID         Key
   1         "hello, dog food, this, water"
   2         "wow nice, love, yes"
   3         "1997"
   4           
   5         "blabla, lol, icecream, nice wow, seriously not"
              ....
   .
   .
   .
```

so basically, everything lowercase, removing 2 letters words, removing any symbol that is not alphanumeric.

thank you very much in advance in advance for your help!

Comment: Show expected output.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck done, hope it's clearer now, the fact is that, whatever operation I want to do with regex I want to make sure that commas stay where they are.

Comment: Couldn't you just do what you had then replace the spaces with commas? Seems like the easiest option to me.

Comment: @HanselPalencia I am not sure if I understand what you are suggesting. If I substituted the spaces with commas I would have every single word separated by a comma, and I don't want this. As I want group of words to be separated by commas as they are noe (i.e. some words are alone like the word "hello" while others are not like in the case "wow nice"

Comment: Makes sense, didn't notice that my mistake

Comment: How does `This is it2` become `this` and not `this is it`, but `wow! nice` becomes `wow nice`? Also, why does `34 l lol` become `lol` and not `l lol` - same goes for `#nice #wow d` to `nice wow`?

Comment: @ctwheels because I get rid of the number from it2 then get rid of words with only 2 letters. But this is relatively less important, my mine concern in not to cancel the commas while erasing any other symbol

Comment: I found an improper way to avoid getting rid of the commas, even though I'm sure there must be some better way: basically I can use    data$keys <- stringr::str_replace_all(data$keys,"AAAA", ",")  to replace commas with AAAA, then apply all the regex cleaning I want to do, and finally reconvert AAAA to commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to accomplish this?

This is a four-step process:

1. Remove special characters and numbers inside words
2. Remove 2-character or less words.
3. Clean up extra spaces
4. Convert to lowercase characters

---

### The logic

#### Task 1 - remove unwanted characters

See this regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/L9tXZe/3)

```
[^a-z\d\s,]+|(?<!\d)\d+(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])\d+(?!\d)
```

How it works:

- Match one of the following options:

  - `[^a-z\d\s,]+` match one or more of any character not present in the set:

    - So this matches any character that isn't `a-z` (or `A-Z` since we add use `i` case-insensitive matching by adding `ignore.case=T` to the `gsub` function), doesn't match digit characters `\d`, or whitespace `\s`, or comma `,`
  - `(?<!\d)\d+(?=[a-z])` match any digits preceding an alpha character (catches digits in words like `33www` or `w3w3w`)

    - `(?<!\d)` ensures what precedes is not a digit
    - `\d+` match one or more digits
    - `(?=[a-z])` ensure what follows is an alpha character
  - `(?<=[a-z])\d+` match any digits following an alpha character (reverse of previous alternation, but catches digits at the end of words like `it2`)

    - `(?<=[a-z])` ensures what precedes is an alpha character
    - `\d+` matches one or more digits

#### Task 2 - remove unwanted words

See this regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/L9tXZe/5)

```
\b[a-z\d]{1,2}\b
```

How it works:

- `\b` assert position as a word boundary (we stripped away `_` in previous task, so no issue there)
- `[a-z\d]{1,2}` matches one or two letter words and digits (case-insensitive - same as previous regex)
- `\b` assert position as a word boundary

#### Task 3 - remove unwanted spaces

See regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/L9tXZe/6)

```
(?<= ) +| +(?=,|$)
```

How it works:

- `(?<= ) +` matches one or more spaces that follow a space character, or
- `+(?=,|$)` matches one or more spaces that precede `,` or the end of the line

#### Task 4 - lowercase conversion

[r](/questions/tagged/r) has the following function:

```
tolower(x)
```

---

See code in use [here](https://tio.run/##lU5NS8NAED2bX/GaesiSqdAqSKGhghe9eMot20o@1hhYu7KbmlTjb4@z0YvehJlhPt6b9@w49tgsUEbBWXintDaEytSPeDKmIqTPjYOPdkXo8lbZkBjYmW6GQ1MqgjZvXE/KTYflen09NVMpdM5BuLyCZqAm3NyX6taq/IUw93zM@RVYyCnbmKPTJzyYNgxEMLmq3bGIwmyfL96lrKR0tIuHaLuZ8SQ442ibZHzcCb/9af0@JLAF9IRXZXWSEpr6YKy6KHOnkvTXeymL7Ftg97Gk1SfP/6F7YQjEA7wbGs7FX7YIWqNNp2zUi3H8Ag)

```
x <- c(
    "Hello, dog_ food, This is it2, water",
    "wow! nice, love, yes",
    "1997",
    "",
    "blabla, 34 l lol, @IceCream, #nice #wow d, seriously Not"
)
x <- gsub("[^a-z\\d\\s,]+|(?<!\\d)\\d+(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])\\d+", "", x, perl=T, ignore.case=T)
x <- gsub("\\b[a-z\\d]{1,2}\\b", "", x, perl=T, ignore.case=T)
x <- gsub("(?<= ) +| +(?=,|$)", "", x, perl=T)
tolower(x)
```

Outputs:

```
[1] "hello, dog food, this, water"                  
[2] "wow nice, love, yes"                           
[3] "1997"                                          
[4] ""                                              
[5] "blabla, lol, icecream, nice wow, seriously not"
```